# specifying project version in gradle.properties for gradle build

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I specified the project version in gradle.properties (previously, it was in build.gradle).  I check for the version in build.gradle and the current logic fails for me (while it works if I move the same version statement to build.gradle):

**gradle.properties**

```
version '0.0.7-SNAPSHOT'
```

**build.gradle**

```
println(project.version)  //I have tried version instead of project.version
ext.isSnapshot = project.version.endsWith("-SNAPSHOT")
println(isSnapshot)  //prints SNAPSHOT if I copy version to build.gradle
if (project.version.endsWith("-SNAPSHOT")) {
    println("*****this is a SNAPSHOT build*****")
} else {
    println("*****this is a RELEASE build*****")
}
```

Any thoughts on what might be causing this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `gradle.properties` have a different syntax, it is a standard Java properties file.

So try:

```
version:0.0.7-SNAPSHOT
```

Comment: works - adding the colon and removing the inverted commas which was throwing off the endsWith logic